# Jetty server best IDE

Tags: jetty

I want to use Jetty 8.0 Server for my application. Which IDE i will use for simple configuration.

Presently i am using Eclipse. How to configure jetty in Eclipse. Any best example?

Answer (score 2):

I use run-jetty-run, and jetty with maven in eclipse.

http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/

More on jetty maven plugins:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin

Answer (score 2):

I use run-jetty-run with DCEVM for hotdeploy.

Here's my tutorial, [Spring-mvc + Velocity + DCEVM](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/)

Answer (score 0):

Most people I know simply write a small embedded usage of jetty for their application.  It is dead simple to do and there are a number of examples in the example-jetty-embedded project in jetty git repository.  It is also how most of our test cases are written, using jetty itself to test.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded

If your using maven then the jetty-maven-plugin is a pretty simple way of testing and works with the eclipse plugin Webby which streamlines much of the pain and suffered that is called WTP.

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Maven+WAR+Plugin

There is also a Jetty WTP plugin that many people use successfully.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin

Comment: The only problem using maven to jetty:run is that it takes too long to startup. RunJettyRun plugin is very fast.

Comment: sure, but then you have to contend with actually _using_ eclipse for something other then editing code which it barely manages doing that at times....so I'll freely admit a bias towards non-IDE tooling :)

Comment: The guy who asked the question is already using Eclipse.. RunJettyRun is a good solution for what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I also use run-jetty-run for Eclipse.

I tried the Jetty plugin for NetBeans, but it didn't work.

I think Jetty for Eclipse is better than Tomcat, cause its simpler to use and configure and a fast server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup M2Eclipse plugin within Eclipse correctly and your project is configured to use Maven, I've found [Jetty Maven Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) within Eclipse to be particularly useful. The beauty of this approach is that you can do your development really fast, especially if you have 3rd party dependencies.  All you have to do is add the following plugin to your pom.xml:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
     <plugins>
         ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
        <configuration>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
          ...
    </plugins>
</build>
    ...
</project>
```

To use this plugin successfully here some additional notes on installation and usage:

## Eclipse Integration

**Install the following Eclipse Plugins first**

- Maven Integration for Eclipse (Help > Eclipse Marketplace...)
- A patch that makes it possible to [debug source code](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384065) at runtime. [Eclipse Plugin Link](http://ifedorenko.github.com/m2e-extras/)

**Next, create a "Maven Build" Eclipse Launcher**

You also need to configure "Maven Build" launcher so that you can run the Jetty Server quickly. Follow the instructions below create this launcher:

- Right-click on your current project and select **(Run As/Debug As) > Maven Build...**
- Set Goals As **rhubarb:start**
- Check **Resolve Workspace artifacts**
- Save

Going forward, you can simply do: **(Run As/Debug As) > Maven Build**, and the goal will execute.